# Is current directory always in the search path of gdb

Tags: gdb, search-path

I noticed that when I use gdb I can use either

```
$ gdb ./main
```

or

```
$ gdb main
```

Is the current directory guaranteed to be in the search path of gdb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  GDB will first try to access the file exactly as specified, so in this case as a relative path from the current directory.  In both of these cases you'll find main.  This will obviously also work if you give an absolute path, like: `gdb /path/to/main`.

If the file can't be found exactly as specified then GDB will search the environment `$PATH` just like a shell will, so `gdb main` will hunt for `main` along your `$PATH`, but `gdb foo/main` will not find `main` under `foo` along your `$PATH`.